# Exibir|Escoder um campo ao selecionar dado no Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Neste código aparece o select com as Cidades agrupadas da forma que desejo, porém gostaria que ao clicar em alguma das opções de 'loja' do select fosse aberto em alguma tabela abaixo o endereço da loja selecionada apenas.

HTML

```
<div> <select id="cities"></select> </div>

<div> <select id="loja selecionada"></select> </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var values = [
{ "Estado": "São Paulo",
  "OrderID": "Loja1",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"},
{"Estado": "São Paulo",
  "OrderID": "Loja2",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"}, 
{ "Estado": "São Paulo",
  "OrderID": "Loja3",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"}, 
{ "Estado": "Rio de Janeiro",
  "OrderID": "Loja1",  
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"},
{ "Estado": "São Paulo", 
  "OrderID": "Loja4",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"}, 
{ "Estado": "Mato Grosso",
  "OrderID": "Loja5",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"},
{ "Estado": "São Paulo", 
  "OrderID": "Loja6",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"}, 
{ "Estado": "Minas Gerais",
  "OrderID": "Loja1",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"},
{ "Estado": "São Paulo",
  "OrderID": "Loja7",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"},
{ "Estado": "Minas Gerais", 
  "OrderID": "Loja2",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"}, 
{ "Estado": "São Paulo", 
  "OrderID": "Loja8",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10"}
];

var items = {},
base, key;
$.each(values, function(index, val) {
key = val.Estado;
if (!items[key]) {
   items[key] = [];
}
items[key].push(val.OrderID);
});

var $select = $('#cities');
$.each(items, function(index, val) {

var optgroup = $('<optgroup>');
    optgroup.attr('label', index);

$.each(val, function(index, val) {
    optgroup.append($('<option>', {
    text: val
    }));
});

$select.append(optgroup);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a montagem das options para gravar o index:

```
$.each(val, function(index, val) {
  optgroup.append($('<option>', {
    text: val,
    value: index //index
  }));
});
```

depois basta implementar no change do select para pegar o endereço e exibir no campo:

```
$('#cities').change(function() {
  var endereco = values[$(this).val()].Endereco;
  $('#endereco').text(endereco);
});
```

HTML:

```
<label>Endereço: <span id="endereco"></span></label>
```

Segue [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/hz818akz/2/) :)

Comment: Bruno, desta forma ele pega pela posição do campo, note que no Fiddle é possível verificar que ao selecionar a 'loja1' abaixo de 'Rio de Janeiro' ele não mostra 'Rua 4' que seria a rua respectiva a loja do Rio de Janeiro e sim 'Rua 1' pegando da primeira posição

Comment: de uma olhada nesse [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/hz818akz/3/), realmente estava errado, a alteração que fiz foi guardar o index do elemento no array base. Se estiver correto me avise que irei atualizar na resposta :)

Comment: Bruno, obrigado pela ajuda, se eu quiser inserir um outro campo por exemplo:
{ "Estado": "São Paulo", 
  "OrderID": "Loja8",
  "Endereco":"Rua 10", "Quantidade":"19"}

E mostrar na tela juntamente com o 'Endereço' a 'Quantidade', de que maneira devo proceder?

Comment: @CRAJ, é bem simples, fiz um exeplo no próprio [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/hz818akz/5/) se tiver alguma duvida estou a disposição :)

Comment: Brunno, me expressei mal, o que desejo é no caso criar um campo desta forma: { "Estado": "São Paulo", "OrderID": "Loja8", "Endereco":"Rua 10", "src":"endereconoMaps"} e fazer com que o valor dentro do html no <iframe src='endereconoMaps' width='600' height='450' frameborder='0' style='border:0' allowfullscreen></iframe> se altere quando o usuario clicar na loja desejada, é possível?

Comment: @CRAJ, qual Api gera esse iframe para você ?

Comment: A própria API do Google Meu Negócio

Comment: @CRAJ eu não conheço a API, mais provavelmente na documentação deve ter algum método que aceita como paramentro as cordenadas e re-desenha o mapa. No caso seria só chamar ele dentro do change, passando as ordenadas. Mais por não ter conhecimento da API não consigo te ajudar muite hehe'